# unable to set foreign key mysql

Tags: mysql

I am developing a patch version which is by create or update existing table by using raw sql.When I ran these 3 queries like below

first query Success

```
CREATE TABLE ts_overtime_scheme_histories( id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
name VARCHAR(255), 
workdays INT, 
break_payable VARCHAR(25), 
roundable VARCHAR(25), 
round_rule VARCHAR(10), round_minute INT, 
type enum('ratio','fixed') DEFAULT 'ratio', 
overtime_request_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id), 
FOREIGN KEY(overtime_request_id) REFERENCES ts_overtime_requests(id) );
```

Second query success

```
CREATE TABLE ts_overtime_scheme_details_histories( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
hour FLOAT, 
ratio FLOAT, 
overtime_scheme_history_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

And now I am trying to connect second table to the first table. So the first table has foreign key on the second table. So I ran the third query

```
ALTER TABLE ts_overtime_scheme_details_histories ADD FOREIGN KEY (`overtime_scheme_history_id`) REFERENCES `ts_overtime_scheme_histories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But somehow it failed. The error report is below

```
General error: 1005 Can't create table `db_test`.`#sql-ea4_28` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: ALTER TABLE ts_overtime_scheme_details_histories
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`overtime_scheme_history_id`) REFERENCES `ts_overtime_scheme_histories` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;)
```

Can somebody help me to find what I miss? At first, I suspect the primary and foreign key data length is not similar, but when I double checked, it is correct.

Edit:
table **ts_overtime_requests** was created using laravel framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column datatype of the foreign key column must match *exactly* the datatype of referenced key column.

In this case, the reported behavior (Error 1005) is expected because there's a difference in the datatypes of the two columns.

One of the columns is signed integer, the other column is `UNSIGNED` integer.

Quick fix would be to change the datatype of `overtime_scheme_history_id` so that is is signed. (Remove the `UNSIGNED` keyword.)